# drag on CCLayer sometimes working

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Im having trouble to get the touches to work on a Custom class

```
-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

NSSet *allTouch = [event allTouches];
UITouch *touch = [[allTouch allObjects]objectAtIndex:0];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];


DragItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:

             Bubble01,
             Bubble02,
             Bubble03,
             Bubble04,
             Bubble05,
             Bubble06,
             nil];

for(int i = 0; i < [DragItems count]; i++)
{
    sprite = (Bubble *)[DragItems  objectAtIndex:i];
    //sprite = (CCSprite *)[DragItems  objectAtIndex:i];
    //if(CGRectContainsPoint([sprite boundingBox], location))
        if(sprite.tag ==12 && CGRectContainsPoint([sprite boundingBox],location))
    {
        selectedSprite = sprite;
        //[self reorderChild:sprite z:BubbleDepthOntop];
    }
    }
  }


-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
//Move touched sprite
NSSet *allTouch = [event allTouches];
UITouch *touch = [[allTouch allObjects]objectAtIndex:0];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];

selectedSprite.position = ccp(location.x, location.y);
NSLog(@"Position: %f %f",location.x, location.y);
}

-(void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
NSSet *allTouch = [event allTouches];
UITouch *touch = [[allTouch allObjects]objectAtIndex:0];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];


selectedSprite = nil;
isTouched = NO;

}
```

//little weird things...
I can drag the sprites (6 bubbles) but but not every-time
(they suddenly stall or if i drag my finger on an empty part of the screen a sprite suddenly jumps to that location from nowhere

I can drag but cant re-drag the same sprite
I'm pretty new at this stuff so I guess I'm missing something simple, any help would be great

I have made a video of what is happening, using my old code, which has worked in other projects of mine - you'll see that the touches are working, but the object (Bubble*) is having trouble understanding that it is deselected. -

Normally I have only been using CCSprite, so I think that it is likely that im doing something wrong with the (Bubble*) class working with the touches

"selectedSprite = nil" isn't working

sometimes the custom class sprite can drag correctly, sometimes another (Bubble*) jumps to the current position of the touch (it should be impossible to drag my finger on an empty section of the screen and have a sprite appear there and yet ><....)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHaTpiVPP_w&feature=youtu.be

```
//custom sprite
#import "CCSprite.h"
#import "cocos2d.h"


@interface Bubble : CCLayer
{
CCSprite *BackBubble;
CCSprite *FrontShine;
CCRepeatForever *REP;
CCLabelTTF *BubbleLabel;
}


@property (nonatomic, strong)CCSprite *BackBubble;
@property (nonatomic, strong)CCSprite *FrontShine;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CCLabelTTF *BubbleLabel;

 -(id)initWithBubbleWithLabel:(NSString*)Bubblepng opacity:(float)myOpacty gloss:(NSString*)glossypng posX:(float)X posY:(float)Y data:(int)myNumber;

@end
```

////

```
@implementation Bubble
@synthesize BackBubble,FrontShine,BubbleLabel;


-(id)initWithBubbleWithLabel:(NSString*)Bubblepng opacity:(float)myOpacty gloss:(NSString*)glossypng posX:(float)X posY:(float)Y data:(int)myNumber
{
self=[super init];
{
    BackBubble = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:Bubblepng];
    BackBubble.position = ccp(X,Y);
    [self addChild: BackBubble z:5];


    FrontShine = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:glossypng];
    FrontShine.position =     ccp(BackBubble.contentSize.width/2,BackBubble.contentSize.height/2);
    [BackBubble addChild: FrontShine z:5];

    //BubbleLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",myNumber]] fontName:@"Grinched" fontSize:35];
    BubbleLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",myNumber]] fontName:@"Helvetica" fontSize:35];
    BubbleLabel.position = ccp(FrontShine.contentSize.width/2, FrontShine.contentSize.height/2);
    BubbleLabel.color = ccc3(255,255,255);
    [BackBubble addChild:BubbleLabel z:200];
    BubbleLabel.opacity =myOpacty;

}
return self;
}
```

the Bubble sprites are being being added to level01 layer as child
then moved wth the following code:

```
 -(void)Scrolltick:(ccTime)ScrollTime
{
[self ScrollSprite:ScrollTime mySprite:Bubble01];
[self ScrollSprite:ScrollTime mySprite:Bubble02];
[self ScrollSprite:ScrollTime mySprite:Bubble03];
[self ScrollSprite:ScrollTime mySprite:Bubble04];
[self ScrollSprite:ScrollTime mySprite:Bubble05];
[self ScrollSprite:ScrollTime mySprite:Bubble06];
}
-(void)ScrollSprite:(ccTime)dt mySprite:(Bubble*)mySprite
{
int MaxHeightofBubbles = 350;
int minHeightofBubbles = 150;

RandomNumber = [self generateRandomNumberBetweenMin:minHeightofBubbles Max:MaxHeightofBubbles];
float ConvertedRandom = [[NSNumber numberWithInt: RandomNumber] floatValue];

mySprite.position = ccp(mySprite.position.x+BubbleSpeed,mySprite.position.y);
if (mySprite.position.x >= 1024+1)
{
    mySprite.position = ccp (0-[mySprite boundingBox].size.width,ConvertedRandom);  //mySprite.position.y+ConvertedRandom
    bubbleStartAgain = YES;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `CGRectContainsPoint([sprite boundingBox],location))`
use `[self isTouchOnSprite:location:sprite]`

```
-(BOOL) isTouchOnSprite:(CGPoint)touch:(CCSprite*)clip{
    CGPoint local = [self convertToNodeSpace:touch];
    Boolean b = CGRectContainsPoint([clip boundingBox], local);
    if (b) {
        return YES;
    }else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

updated project [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8t1yL46Hq_FNE9EUG5zVUU2Zzg&authuser=0)
let me know if this works .

Comment: Thanks Rahul
a couple of problems with the code:

'touch' used as the name of the previous parameter rather than as part of the selector

unused var "local"

I fixed these and changed the pointer to (CCSprite*) to be the custom class (Bubble *), but no luck it doesn't return the touch, thanks for the suggestion though, ill try a few other ideas and see how that goes.

Comment: @Natty : ok . i missed type the local .. use local instead of touch.. changed my answer ... you can also use `CCTargetedTouchDelegate` within your custom class `Bubble` . i faced similar problem with one of my game . i use touch for each of the sprite instead . `ccTouchBegan`.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, I have made a video of what is happening, using my old code - you'll see that the touches are working, but the object (Bubble*) is having trouble understanding that it is deselected.

"selectedSprite = nil" isn't working

 sometimes the custom class sprite can drag correctly, sometimes another (Bubble*) jumps to the current position of the touch

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHaTpiVPP_w&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @Natty : which cocos2d version are you using.? ...........
is the CCLayer class is using any physics engine?...........
arr you moving the Bubble Objects separately?..........

will try to make a demo using custom class and ping back ..

Comment: Thanks Rahul, Ive added the Bubble class, the bubbles should all move separately at different speeds across the screen (moving to the right of the screen, then at pos 1024+1 - they get moved back to the beginning of the screen pos 0 - the y position is randomised)

there are no physics in the scene, only the bubble sprites loaded onto the level01 layer.

I am running cocos2d-iphone v2.1

Comment: @Natty : i made a sample File similar to your above code . which is working .. [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8t1yL46Hq_FZEF6aEtpWndQaFU&authuser=0) ..  let me know if you find it use full .. i used older version of `cocos2d 1.0` . still let me know if you got my point .

Comment: Thanks Rahul, I tried using your code, there is a problem however, since I need to use a custom init to load the sprites (when I use my custom init I no longer receive the touches at all) NSLog(@"ccTouchMoved:"); doesn't seem to log or touches ended,

I have made a modified project using your code and loading the sprite shee, thanks for your help so far.


https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8yag1LtEfYSRlY5N3d0RXhnMTg&usp=sharing

Comment: @Natty :  just add `[self setContentSize:[BackBubble boundingBox].size];
[self setAnchorPoint:ccp(0,0)];`
in your `initWithBubbleWithLabel` method ... have updated the project file. please check .[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8t1yL46Hq_FTHNiLXNDeW1URGs&authuser=0)

Comment: however the touches still dont awyas work (ill have a little look - maybe something else is messing with them) anyway thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Natty : updated the project file .. [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8t1yL46Hq_FNE9EUG5zVUU2Zzg&authuser=0)