# Having trouble deselecting my CCSprite on drag event, selectedSprite = nil not working

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm using code that has previously worked in other project the only difference is that this time I'm using a custom sprite class which seems to be not deselecting itself
Ive made a video here of the problem

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHaTpiVPP_w&feature=youtu.be

```
-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

NSSet *allTouch = [event allTouches];
UITouch *touch = [[allTouch allObjects]objectAtIndex:0];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];


DragItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:

         Bubble01,
         Bubble02,
         Bubble03,
         Bubble04,
         Bubble05,
         Bubble06,
         nil];

for(int i = 0; i < [DragItems count]; i++)
{
sprite = (Bubble *)[DragItems  objectAtIndex:i];
//if(sprite.tag ==12 && CGRectContainsPoint([sprite boundingBox],location))
if(CGRectContainsPoint([sprite boundingBox], location))
{
    selectedSprite = sprite;
}
}
}


-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
//Move touched sprite
NSSet *allTouch = [event allTouches];
UITouch *touch = [[allTouch allObjects]objectAtIndex:0];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];

selectedSprite.position = ccp(location.x, location.y);
NSLog(@"Position: %f %f",location.x, location.y);
}

-(void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
NSSet *allTouch = [event allTouches];
UITouch *touch = [[allTouch allObjects]objectAtIndex:0];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];

selectedSprite = nil;

}
```

Comment: try to see if you get 'touchCancelled' events. If yes, you need to manage state there too.

Comment: thanks Yves.....hmmm no luck there, it still seems to "keep the last sprite", it has fixed the the issue if I drag my finger on screen that a sprite jumps too that area though... but Im still not able to drag the sprites when i touch them.

Comment: With the help of @rahul_send89 we found the problem (the layer content size needed to be set) this was messing up the touches
[self setContentSize:[BackBubble boundingBox].size]; [self setAnchorPoint:ccp(0,0)];

Comment: answer and accept then, so that the list is accurate regarding this. Luck with the game :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[drag on CCLayer sometimes working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388171/drag-on-cclayer-sometimes-working/26459061?noredirect=1#comment41569705_26459061)

With the very kind help of rahul_send89 we solved the problem,
firstly the custom class a cclayer was changed to accept its own touches, then in the init
[self setContentSize:[BackBubble boundingBox].size]; was used to size the layer 
(so other touches fire, this is what was probably messing up the touches for me)

the link above contains all the code. thanks again for the help!